# how to change clipPath on an image

Tags: svg

Is there a way to change the `clip-path` attribute of an image to another `clipPath` element?

seems `setAttribute('clip-path', newClipPath)` doesn't work.

Comment: To be clear: the attribute is 'clip-path' and the corresponding element is called 'clipPath'. And yes, it should work, but without more details it's hard to say what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at here http://jsfiddle.net/GhRnn/2/
The Google logo is clipped using different clip paths, defined in def section.
Click on the buttons, to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this example. It works fine in Firefox 10.0.1 but "clip for horizontal center" failed in chrome 16. And I also noticed a lot of svg implementation differences among browsers, especially when doing clipping and animation.