# how to clip (or mask) google map

Tags: html, google-maps, css, svg, clipping

I have a google map running correctly.Now I want that map to be clipped to a bubble shape.It's not the pointer/market I am talking about, it's the entire map which has to be masked with a bubble overlay.Currently the map is in rectangular shape.

I have uploaded sample image.

http://s17.postimg.org/v26nk9p4f/mapbg.png

To be honest I am not sure if this is possible at all as before I explored some svg options and it doesn't seem to work with all browsers.

I could use the bubble as overlay at the top of the map but the overlay img has to be transparent and the background div has a different color.So that's the problem.

Is there any other trick or suggestions I can use to achieve the same out-put.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! Have you managed to clip the map as you asked? I'm currently stuck at trying to do the same. :-/

Comment: No mate...it's still on hold...I am not getting time to do the research. The main thing with this is to create the bubble.

Comment: That's too bad :-/ I have a deadline until November 15th to do that and will let you know if I succeed

Comment: Oh...that's not good then..I will try in the weekend again. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to view only a part of the map...like say only india?

Comment: Shirish you need to explore google map api for that. You need a specific lat/lng for that. To display a part of a map is different with the question I have posted. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Create a bubble shaped [clipPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath) and apply that to the map using the clip-path property.

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325819/how-to-change-clippath-on-an-image) has an dynamic example which may be more complicated than you need but should show you the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Robert for showing me the light.I will try to follow that clipPath property.Only concern is that even If I am able to do ,I won't be able to add any shadow to the outerside of the bubble.

Comment: You could use an feGaussianBlur to blur the clipped image. If you get stuck you could always ask another question.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the suggestion.The problem is that in the background there will be html content(google map) and not an image.Just wondering if there is any sample bubble clipping code for any text in background.Just a starting point to go towards the right path.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this post and had a hard time trying to sort this out, but here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/AndreGCRamos/ffda38813e81bad1e10c/) of what I came up with.
I used the path of an SVG I exported from Sketch, it still needs a bit of tweaking but have fun with it.

**index.html**

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBSDlMWErr_gwT5d5wze8oK9muKPuHLtKQ">
    </script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="0" height="0">
  <clipPath id="chopChop">
    <path id="svgPath" d="M458.306721,357.359262 L458.306721,154.888126 C458.306721,154.888126 458.306721,123.735028 431.347502,108.158479 L330.082536,49.6444164 L330.082536,49.6684173 L256.112579,6.92291067 C256.112579,6.92291067 229.15336,-8.65363834 202.194141,6.92291067 L26.9592189,108.158479 C26.9592189,108.158479 1.13686838e-13,123.735028 1.13686838e-13,154.888126 L1.13686838e-13,357.359262 C1.13686838e-13,357.359262 1.13686838e-13,388.51236 26.9592189,404.088909 L202.194141,505.324477 C202.194141,505.324477 229.15336,520.901026 256.112579,505.324477 L351.765039,450.050529 L431.347502,404.088909 C431.347502,404.088909 458.306721,388.51236 458.306721,357.359262"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path id="svgMask" d="M458.306721,357.359262 L458.306721,154.888126 C458.306721,154.888126 458.306721,123.735028 431.347502,108.158479 L330.082536,49.6444164 L330.082536,49.6684173 L256.112579,6.92291067 C256.112579,6.92291067 229.15336,-8.65363834 202.194141,6.92291067 L26.9592189,108.158479 C26.9592189,108.158479 1.13686838e-13,123.735028 1.13686838e-13,154.888126 L1.13686838e-13,357.359262 C1.13686838e-13,357.359262 1.13686838e-13,388.51236 26.9592189,404.088909 L202.194141,505.324477 C202.194141,505.324477 229.15336,520.901026 256.112579,505.324477 L351.765039,450.050529 L431.347502,404.088909 C431.347502,404.088909 458.306721,388.51236 458.306721,357.359262"  />
</svg>
```

**script.js**

```
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: 52.517010, lng: 13.378540},
      zoom: 14,
      styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#193341"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#2c5a71"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#29768a"},{"lightness":-37}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#406d80"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#406d80"}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#3e606f"},{"weight":2},{"gamma":0.84}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"weight":0.6},{"color":"#1a3541"}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#2c5a71"}]}],
      disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**style.css**

```
html, body, #map-canvas { height: 530px;width: 460px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#map-canvas{
  /*Chrome,Safari*/
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#chopChop);

  /* Firefox*/
  clip-path: url(#chopChop);

  /* iOS support */
   -webkit-mask: url(#chopChop);
}
```

Comment: That's pretty nice. Now you just need to figure out how to ignore mouse events on top of the clip path.